# Pygame installation error; Missing DLL

Tags: python, pygame

I've recently started learning python. So I installed pygame into Python folder and when I try to import it in SHELL it gives me this error:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in
> <module>
>     import pygame   File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 99, in
> <module>
>     from pygame.base import * ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found. I was installing python-3.4.3 and
> pygame-1.9.2a0.win32-py3.2
```

Answer (score 0):

To install pygame you run the .msi binary, not in the python folder specifically. The error above says that you have installed part of pygame, but not all of it correctly.

> ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Python is saying that the run file is installed, but not other modules of pygame are in their correct location. My advice is remove whatever pygame files are installed and re-install pygame, but not python.

Edit: I would put this as a comment, but as I have just joined stack overflow I can't comment so I added extra information to create an answer.